# Prove that for any integers x,y there are integers a,b such that gcd(x,y) = ax + by

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would I go about proving that: For any integers x,y there are integers a,b such that gcd(x,y) = ax + by?

One thing I noticed is that when x is a multiple of y or vice versa, the smaller number is automatically the gcd; thus, in those situations, the value multiplied by the smaller number would be 1 and the value multiplied by the larger number would be 0 and we would have an "a,b" which would be "1,0" or "0,1".  However, in other cases it's a bit more complicated, and we also have negative integers, of course.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This property is called Bezout's identity. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the Bezout lemma and one proof is [here](https://bytebucket.org/sivaramambikasaran/my_notes/raw/3ae704eed784fd68bc565366e2fb0bb849e4b6d6/Bezout_Lemma/Bezout_Lemma.pdf?at=master)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A non constructive proof: consider the set
$$
X=\{ax+by: x,y\in\mathbb{Z}, ax+by>0\}
$$
and prove that

1. $X\ne\emptyset$;
2. if $d$ is the minimum element in $X$, then $d=\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful!